# How to switch different views in one view controller

Tags: ios

How to switch different views in one view controller.I have to design a app that has five views in one view controller and the views contains some text fileds.if i fill the text fileds in first view it should enter to the another view.that another view contains text fields.

Comment: where is code ? that you try before post question here.

Comment: What OS? iOS? macOS? tvOS?

Comment: design in ios for mobile app

Answer (score 0):

Try this in Objective-C

Switch view with animation

```
CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
transition.duration = 0.5;
transition.type = kCATransitionPush;
transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromRight;
[transition setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];
[self.superView addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];
[self.superView addSubview:self.chieldView];
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can do it by using container view with changing alpha of your (5 views) so when you are on first view its alpha becomes 1 while others will be 0 and so on